# Excel - is there a solution for autocomplete in dropdowns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, autocomplete

I know this feature was introduced to Excel and removed since it was buggy. It's working in Excel online but VBA doesn't, and I need it too.

I am looking for ideas to get the same functionality because I have to choose names from a list that is now 400 long and will get longer.

This is my current version Microsoft® Excel® LTSC MSO Version 2108 build(16.0.14332.20631) 64-bit

Thanks.

Hanan Cohen

Comment: That feature has been introduced again in `MS365` current channel, working on my end. You are using `Excel 2021` probably its not there. May be with `VBA` but i am not sure abt it!